# HTML to CSV PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, csv

I've been trying to export MySQL fields to CSV and can get all them exporting correctly except the filed which contains HTML.

My MySQL table is made up as follows:

Name: Address: Profile:

Name is simply text as with address, but profile is HTML

My array is:

```
$array = array ( array ( "Name" => "$name", "Address" => "$address", "Profile" => $profile )
);
```

Made using:

```
$name = $info['name'];
$address = $info['address'];
$profile = $info['profile'];
```

I have a "Tab" \t delimiter and every exports into the CSV correctly bar the HTML which I would like to keep as pure HTML but in one Excel field, at the moment is splits across multi rows and fields.

CSV code is as follows:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$titleArray = array_keys($array[0]);
$delimiter = "\t";
$filename="profiles.xls";
foreach ($array as $subArrayKey => $subArray) {
 $dataRowString = implode($delimiter, $subArray);
    print $dataRowString . "\r\n";
}
```

Any help or advise would be highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the field values. You can use `fputcsv`:

```
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv($stdout, $subArray, "\t");
```

---

```
$filename="profiles.xls";
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$titleArray = array_keys($array[0]);
$delimiter = "\t";
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
foreach ($array as $subArrayKey => $subArray) {
    fputcsv($stdout, $subArray, $delimiter);
}
```

Comment: Hi maybe my head has been at this to long, can you explain which part of my CSV code above I have to modify and put the above coding in if you don't mind.?

Comment: Sure, no problem, see the updated answer. I also saw that you have a small bug in your code, `$filename` is used in the headers but defined later. I moved it up.

Comment: Getting a 500 Internal Server Error. :(

Comment: Sorted by Changing php://stdout  to php://output


Thanks for the help, this has been driving me crazy.. Very much appreciated. :)